# How to convert single child xml element to Json Array using XSLT

Tags: json, xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I am using a generic xslt(http://www.bizcoder.com/convert-xml-to-json-using-xslt) to convert xml into json which works just fine when there are multiple array elements in request and now I want to convert a particular xml element even tough it has single child element.For example:

Sample XML

```
<messages>
<message>
<to>Karim</to>
<from>Tom</from>
<heading>Reminder</heading>
<body>Please check your email !</body>
</message>
</messages>
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<Response>
<Info id="10485824">
<Data tipus="11" megnevezes="APEH hátralék (rendezetlen)">
<Value num="1" subtype="xbool">false</Value>
</Data> 
</Info>
</Response>
```

Sample JSON:

```
    {
        "messages": {
            "message": [{
                "to": "Karim",
                "from": "Tom",
                "heading": "Reminder",
                "body": "Please check your email !"
            }]
        }
    }
```

Is there any we can add in the xslt to filter only this element to return as json array always?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the condition to create the array to

```
<!-- Object Properties -->
<xsl:template name="Properties">
    <xsl:variable name="childName" select="name(*[1])"/>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="not(*|@*)">"<xsl:value-of select="."/>"</xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="$childName = 'message' or count(*[name()=$childName]) > 1">{ "<xsl:value-of select="$childName"/>" :[<xsl:apply-templates select="*" mode="ArrayElement"/>] }</xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>{
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
}</xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
    <xsl:if test="following-sibling::*">,</xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Hi Martin,
Thanks for the solution. But after putting the condition attributes are getting missed and not coming in response.
For example sample request:


===================================================
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

        <Response>
            <Info id="10485824">
                
<Data tipus="11" megnevezes="APEH hátralék (rendezetlen)">
<Value num="1" subtype="xbool">false</Value>
                    </Data>
                     
                
            </Info>
        </Response>

Comment: @Diya, I didn't write the original code, I just adapted to work with the input sample and desired output you presented in the original question. If you change your requirements better do that in a new question where you describe the input you have, the output the code you use gives you, the change in that output you need, plus your attempt to adjust the XSLT and how it failed, i.e. the unwanted output.